# if (DateTime.Hour ==10 && DateTime.Minutes == 5) как сделать?

Tags: c#, datetime

Здравствуйте, выручайте есть кусок программы : C#

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
{

    <code>zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataTime", s);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMC", save_txt31_CMC);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCSirieTanki", save_txt31_CMCSirieTanki);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutHotCMC", save_txt31_HotCMC);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCCIP", save_txt31_CMCCIP);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCCIPObram", save_txt31_CMCCIPObram);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCRozliv", save_txt31_CMCRozliv);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMC3", save_txt31_CMC3);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCTara", save_txt31_CMCTara);

}

if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 5 && DateTime.Now.Second == 00)
{

    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataTime", s);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMC", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCSirieTanki", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutHotCMC", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCCIP", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCCIPObram", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCRozliv", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMC3", 0);
    zsutcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutCMCTara", 0); 

}
else
{
 }
```

Вопрос заключается в том как сделать что бы оператор if отрабатывал с минутами если взять

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
```

отлично работает, но если я добавляю минуты:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 5 && DateTime.Now.Second == 00)
```

то он сразу перестаёт работать, а при этом есть ещё место что бы раз в месяц первого числа, подскажите как правильно это реализовать:
на месяц выглядит так:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Day == 1 && DateTime.Now.Hour == 7 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
```

но почему то мне кажется он тоже врял-ли отработает

Comment: Что означает "перестаёт работать?"

Comment: А вы эту функцию каждую секунду точно дергаете? Не может оказаться, что она дергается в 59..01..03..05 секунд, например?

Comment: сделайте вывод `DateTime.Now.Minute`, посмотрите чему равняется, вы скорее всего записываете в неправильном формате в `if`.

Comment: Перестаёт работать в смысле не отрабатывает код который в нём находится, код в правильном формате, я его не дергаю каждую секунду я его дергаю один раз в 10 00, второй раз в 10:05

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, дело в том что секунда не нулевая на момент выполнения.

Сделайте проверку без секунд но с флагом что в эту минуту отработал, например:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 5 && last_minute < DateTime.Now.Minute) {
last_minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
...
}
```

Но вообще, правильнее сделать шедульер на это дело, который будет вызваться в нужный период или нужное время.

Comment: не отрабатывает, можно по подробней?